# Java outputting to text file?

Tags: java

So I am having troubles printing to output. I understand the concept, but when it comes to this problem its kinda weird. I've tried different print lines and all of them give me different results from the console window. I'm still trying different things, but im starting to run out of ideas. Thanks and much appreciated !

This is what I want the expected output to be.

```
1
1, 2, 3, 4
```

When I try println it does this for output.println(data[0]);

```
1
, 2, 3, 4
```

when I do a regular print it does this

```
1, 2, 3, 4
```

This is the text file print method`

```
    public class JavaApplication1 {

  static int[] Array(int[] data) {

      int size = 1;
      if (data !=null) {
          size = 1 +data.length;
      }
      return new int [size];
  }

  private static int[] addToArray(int[] data, int x) {
      int[] array2 = Array(data);
      if(data !=null) {
          System.arraycopy(data,0,array2,0,data.length);
      }
      array2[array2.length - 1] = x;
      return array2;
  }
  private int[] data;

  public JavaApplication1 (int[] data, int x) {
      this.data = addToArray(data, x);      
  }
  public void printall() {
      System.out.print(data[0]);
      for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
          System.out.printf(", %d", data[i]);

      }
      System.out.println();
  } public void text() {
    try {
           PrintWriter output =  new PrintWriter("test.txt");
           output.print(data[0]);
           for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
               output.printf( ", %d", data[i]);
               output.flush();
           }
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }


  }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] in = {1,2,3};
        int[] test = {1,2,3};

        int l = 4;
        int x = 4;

        JavaApplication1 a = new JavaApplication1(null, 1);
        a.printall();
        JavaApplication1 b = new JavaApplication1(in, x);
        b.printall();


        JavaApplication1 c = new JavaApplication1(null, 1);
        c.text();
        JavaApplication1 d = new JavaApplication1(test, l);
        d.text();




    }

}
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Do you want your output to be 1,2,3,4?

Comment: @bkail I am just having problems printing to text file, and would like some help.

Comment: From what I understand, you want your output in a text file, instead of the console?

Comment: @SoumitriPattnaik  I want it to do both

Comment: Are you not getting any out put in your text file ? @madauewo

Comment: @SoumitriPattnaik Yes I am , but the format is weird,look the 2 after the 1st one, that happens when I output it to the text file.

Comment: Uses bufferedwriter

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14503595/write-file-using-bufferedwriter-in-java

Comment: @madauewo find my answer below, I ran that, it works, Thanks :)

Comment: `This is what I want the expected output to be: ...` - that is exactly what I get on the **console** when I run your program. In the text **file**, only the second line is shown, since you are **overwriting** the text file when you run your `text()` method the second time.

Comment: @madauewo, check my answer, try out my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
public void text() {
        try {
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter("test.txt");
            output.println(data[0]);
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (i != (data.length - 1)) {
                    output.printf("%d, ", data[i]);
                } else {
                    output.printf("%d", data[i]);
                }
                output.flush();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }

    }
```

Comment: @madauewo, what is the expected output of your code, if you replace values of test to `int[] test = {4,5,6};`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
PrintWriter output =  new PrintWriter("test.txt");
output.println(data[0]);      //this is where you call the println
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    output.printf( ", %d", data[i]);
    output.flush();
}
```

Comment: This won't work.

First you have a misspelling 'print', it should be 'printf'.
Second it does not produce the output he wants

Comment: @Soumitri Pattnaik, PrintWriter has a print method. Here's the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html

Comment: I know there is a print method. But you have called it wrong, look at all the definitions of print, it takes one argument, but you have two,.

Comment: However, your code still does not produce the out put that he wants

Answer (score 0):

try do in this way

```
public void text() {
    try {
       PrintWriter output =  new PrintWriter("test.txt");

       for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
           if(i > 0){
               output.print(",");
           }

           output.print(data[i]);
           output.flush();     
       }   
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it a new line for each output loop it and add "\n" to each line you write or you can convert to string and  edit String format to whatever you want. You can add a comma if you want

```
string.format()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Cause of problem:** In your code, everytime you call `text()`, you are replacing existing file, without updating or appending new data to it.

Refer this [`SO question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java). You can write printWriter as

```
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.txt", true)));
```

---

I have tested on local, Try this code.

```
public void text() {
    try {
        // Adding data to existing file without replacing it.
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.txt", true)));
        output.print(data[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
            output.printf(", %d", data[i]);
        }
        output.print("\n"); // Added next line in the file
        output.flush();
        output.close(); // closing PrintWriter.
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // log your exception.
    }
}
```